# probability of 2 pairs in a 5 digit number

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

To find the probability of 2 Pairs in a 5 digit number

P(2 Pairs)=$$\dfrac{ \binom{5}{2}}2*1*0.1*{3 \choose 2}*0.9*0.1*0.8=0.108$$

Why is 5C2 divided by 2 ?
We reserve 2 digits for the first pair from the 5 digit, and from the remaining 3 digit, we reserve 2 digit for another pair, so why do we divide 5C2 by 2?

According to my calculation

$$ P(2 Pair)={ \binom{5}{2}}*1*0.1*{3 \choose 2}*0.9*0.1*0.8=0.108$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Is the calculation you showed your own or is it given in an answer key?

Comment: the calculation is given in the answer key, but according to my calculation , I dont find it intuitive to divide the 5C2 by 2. So, any idea to why it is divided?

Comment: I suspect the answer to your question is that if you first select the first and third digits for a $7$ and then select the second and fifth digits for a $9$ yields the same result as first selecting the second and fifth digits for a $9$ and then selecting the first and third digits for a $7$.  It would help if you could show your own calculations for comparison with the answer key.

Answer (score 1):

If you did not divide by $2$, you would be counting a number such as $73979$ twice, once when you selected the first and fourth digits for the $7$'s and then the third and fifth digits for the $9$'s and once when you selected the third and fifth digits for the $9$ and then the first and third digits for the $7$'s.

Here is an alternative approach to the problem:

There are a total of $9 \cdot 10 \cdot 10 \cdot 10 \cdot 10 = 90000$ five-digit positive integers.

We consider two cases.

The leading digit is not repeated:  There are nine ways to choose the leading digit since it cannot be zero.  There are $\binom{9}{2}$ to choose two of the remaining nine digits for the pairs.  There are $\binom{4}{2}$ to choose the positions of the smaller of those digits. 
$$\binom{9}{1}\binom{9}{2}\binom{4}{2}$$

The leading digit is repeated:  There are nine ways to choose the leading digit and four ways to choose the other position for the leading digit.  There are nine ways to choose one of the remaining digits for the other pair and $\binom{3}{2}$ ways to select its positions.  There are eight ways to fill the remaining position with one of the eight remaining digits.
$$\binom{9}{1}\binom{4}{1}\binom{9}{1}\binom{3}{2}\binom{8}{1}$$

Hence, the probability that a five-digit positive integer contains two pairs of digits is 
$$\frac{\binom{9}{1}\binom{9}{2}\binom{4}{2} + \binom{9}{1}\binom{4}{1}\binom{9}{1}\binom{3}{2}\binom{8}{1}}{90000} = \frac{1944 + 7776}{9000} = \frac{9720}{90000} = \frac{1080}{10000} = 0.108$$

Comment: sir, then why is that when we see for the 4 digits, we dont need to divide it by 2, it is simply given by 4C2*1*0.1*0.9*0.1=0.027

Comment: Could you clarify your question?  What four digits are you talking about?

Comment: I meant, instead for taking the five digits,if we consider a four digit number, the probabiliy of getting two pair in a four digit number is 0.027. and here we need not divide it by 2

Comment: I agree that the answer is $0.027$ for the four-digit case.  However, I used the method outlined above.  There are nine ways of choosing the leading digit, three ways to choose the other position for that digit, and nine ways to fill the remaining two positions with another digit, which yields $$\frac{\binom{9}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{9}{1}}{9000} = \frac{243}{9000} = \frac{27}{1000} = 0.027$$  Please explain how you arrived at your answer.

Comment: How did you obtain $0.027$?  $$\binom{4}{2} \cdot 0.1 \cdot 0.9 \cdot 0.1 = 6 \cdot 0.009 = 0.054$$  To get the right answer, you must divide your calculation by $2$.

Comment: oh sorry, one more thing, if it were for 3 pairs in a 6 digit, do we divide it by three ? and thank you

Comment: Given your approach, you would divide by the $3!$ orders in which you could select the same three pairs of digits.

Answer (score 1):

We can choose the two digits appearing twice in ${10\choose2}$ ways, then the single digit in $8$ ways. The five chosen digits can be arranged in ${5!\over 2!2!}$ ways. Multiply by ${9\over10}$ in order to eliminate all numbers with a leading zero. It follows that there are
$${10\choose2}\cdot 8\cdot {5!\over2!2!}\cdot{9\over10}=9720$$
admissible numbers. The probability we are after then comes to
$$p={9720\over90\,000}={27\over250}=0.108\ \ .$$